# I need to build a transmitter/receiver system that can accurately (within 500mm) measure distance between the 2 devices

Tags: transmitter, distance

A business case has been presented to me and I desperately need advice.

I am searching for technologies capable of providing an approximate (<500mm) distance between a stationary receiver and portable (up to 50m away) transmitter.

The distance would need to account for obstructions between the devices and would only be used during daylight hours. Additional devices to assist if line-of-sight was required would be considered.

Any advice on steering me in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: If you have line of sight then laser is what's normally used (during land surveying etc). There's existing products for it as well. Otherwise there's GPS though I don't remember what accuracy it got nowadays. I would guess not as good as +/- 0.5m.

Comment: Many years ago, cameras used ultrasonic ranging to measure the distance to the subject and so to determine the focus.  There use to be such range measuring modules available.

Comment: What kind of research have you done so far, and how do those results fit into your solution space?  You're question is overly broad as it now stands.

Comment: What technologies have you considered and what were your findings? This could be regarded as a homework question and, as with all such questions raised on this site, the "asker" needs to demonstrate effort in finding a solution.